# Array Multiplication in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am having a bit of trouble in multiplying arrays of shape (10,) and (3,) in Numpy, is it possible to multiply both?

CODE:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.60707902, 0.40313125, -0.29449326, 0.38145062, 0.52075884, 0.16759577,
 0.30436678, 0.5042952, 0.29082114, 0.1399974 ])

b = np.array([-0.86029462, 0.47981366, -0.17225568])

print(a * b)
```

The output of the multiplication I want is:

```
  -0.522267   0.291285  -0.104573
  -0.346812   0.193428  -0.069442
   0.253351  -0.141302   0.050728
  -0.328160   0.183025  -0.065707
  -0.448006   0.249867  -0.089704
  -0.144182   0.080415  -0.028869
  -0.261845   0.146039  -0.052429
  -0.433842   0.241968  -0.086868
  -0.250192   0.139540  -0.050096
  -0.120439   0.067173  -0.024115
```

Comment: Use `a*b[:,None]` or `np.outer(a, b)`

Comment: `a[:, None] * b`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. The output I'm getting has a shape (3, 10) but I need a shape of (10, 3)

Answer (score 0):

By using `np.outer()` you can get the desired output:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.60707902, 0.40313125, -0.29449326, 0.38145062, 0.52075884, 0.16759577,
 0.30436678, 0.5042952, 0.29082114, 0.1399974 ])
b = np.array([-0.86029462, 0.47981366, -0.17225568])
print(np.outer(a,b))
```

Output:

```
[[-0.52226681  0.29128481 -0.10457281]
 [-0.34681165  0.19342788 -0.06944165]
 [ 0.25335097 -0.14130189  0.05072814]
 [-0.32815992  0.18302522 -0.06570704]
 [-0.44800603  0.2498672  -0.08970367]
 [-0.14418174  0.08041474 -0.02886932]
 [-0.2618451   0.14603934 -0.05242891]
 [-0.43384245  0.24196773 -0.08686771]
 [-0.25019186  0.13953996 -0.05009559]
 [-0.12043901  0.06717266 -0.02411535]]
```

You can also solve this by working the indices a bit:

```
print(a[::,None]*b)
```

Output:

```
[[-0.52226681  0.29128481 -0.10457281]
 [-0.34681165  0.19342788 -0.06944165]
 [ 0.25335097 -0.14130189  0.05072814]
 [-0.32815992  0.18302522 -0.06570704]
 [-0.44800603  0.2498672  -0.08970367]
 [-0.14418174  0.08041474 -0.02886932]
 [-0.2618451   0.14603934 -0.05242891]
 [-0.43384245  0.24196773 -0.08686771]
 [-0.25019186  0.13953996 -0.05009559]
 [-0.12043901  0.06717266 -0.02411535]]
```

### EDIT

If the output needs to be the opposite then we only need to change the order of the values we're passing:

```
print(b[::,None]*a) #or print(np.outer(b,a))
```

Output:

```
[[-0.52226681 -0.34681165  0.25335097 -0.32815992 -0.44800603 -0.14418174
  -0.2618451  -0.43384245 -0.25019186 -0.12043901]
 [ 0.29128481  0.19342788 -0.14130189  0.18302522  0.2498672   0.08041474
   0.14603934  0.24196773  0.13953996  0.06717266]
 [-0.10457281 -0.06944165  0.05072814 -0.06570704 -0.08970367 -0.02886932
  -0.05242891 -0.08686771 -0.05009559 -0.02411535]]
```

Comment: Hi Celius, thanks for the help. The output I'm getting has a shape (3, 10) but I need a shape of (10, 3)

Comment: But this is what exactly matches the desired output you posted. You can check the edit though.

Comment: Cheers, feel free to accept the answer if it helps!